# Custom Service Account for ASP.NET app pools

Tags: asp.net, iis

As documented in the deprecated Patterns and Practices article below, it used to be best practice to create a custom service account to run ASP.NET applications. This avoided the problem of having to give the generic Network Service account permissions to resources  or having credentials in config files.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649309.aspx

You would simply create a new Windows account, add it as the Custom identity of an app pool and then run  aspnet_regiis –ga to grant the necessary permissions.

Is this still a valid way of doing things? Or has it been supplanted by a better way? I realise that there are AppPoolIdentities now, but they use the machine account for granting permission to databases which strikes me as a bit rubbish.

If I’m still doing it the right way, is there a newer article that isn’t marked as outdated?

Comment: I'm trying to set this up myself.  It seems the right way to me, but I can't get it to work.  There seems a very delicate balance between granting too many permissions and having enough to get the ASP.net site running!

Answer (score 0):

you can set custom service account in IIS as below.

1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
2. In the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application Pools.
3. On the Application Pools page, select the application pool for which you want to specify an identity, and then click Advanced Settings in the Actions pane.
4. For the Identity property, click the ... button to open the Application Pool Identity dialog box.
5. If you want to use a built-in account, select the Built-in account option and select an account from the list.
6. If you want to use a custom identity, select the Custom account option and click Set to open the Set Credentials dialog box. Then type the custom account name in the User name text box, type a password in the Password text box, retype the password in the Confirm password text box, and then click OK.
7. Click OK to dismiss the Application Pool Identity dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the newer article (3/20/2020) that you seek, written by a Microsoft employee:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/premier-field-engineering/iis-best-practices/ba-p/1241577

For what it's worth, he lists Application Pool Identities as a best practice for app pool identity configuration.